# How can I change Kendo Chart's Background Image?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-chart

How can I change Kendo chart's background with this code? Is it possible?

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "background: url('~/shared/pics/harita.png')" })
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make following changes for your chart to display the image in the background.

1. In the chart definition make sure you have set Chart Area background to transperant. 
   See Below:

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().StockChart<ChartModel>()
    .Name("stockDemoChart")
    .................
    .................
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea.Background("transparent"))
   ```
2. Rather than specifying your chart background in the HtmlAttributes you can set it in style against your chart name. See below:

   ```
   <style>
      #stockDemoChart {
      background: center no-repeat url('@Url.Content("~/shared/pics/demo.png")')
      }
   </style>
   ```